# how do i add logo in my site

Tags: customization

I want to add logo to my site how can I add this code `csl_CustomSiteLogo_show_logo()` in the header.php? My website is https:hostsort.com and logo link is this ...https://hostsort.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/SmallLogo.png

I want to remove image texts and put image logo to my site, can you please show me step by steps or can do it for me if you can, I am a beginner here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the code of your `header.php` and maybe someone can show you how to edit it.

Comment: csl_CustomSiteLogo_show_logo() ::::::;;this the code or if any one knows how can

Comment: Or if the is any way someone to help just to show that logo in that site will be appreciate

Comment: That’s a custom function somewhere, probably part of the theme.  We can’t even see what that does.  Have you tried adding the logo using customizer under the Apperances menu in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Given the information and by looking at the site it's hard to know exactly how you can add the logo. If you can give us the theme link/documentation then it will be much easier to know the exact solution. But with my years of knowledge, here are the best possible solutions.

1. You should check "Appearance > Customize", there you might see any settings to add a custom logo.
2. If there are any "Theme Options" for this theme in the backend.